# Codeigniter 1.7.2 404 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been searching a lot and tested several different ways to tackle this... but nothing worked so far. I've just uploaded a website to my server and after all the necessary changes it returned the following error - that I've never seen before.

[This is the screen shot when I first uploaded the files online...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHhFg.png)

Well, after some testing and researching, I've changed the name of my controllers do capitalized - and models - and the "php" part of the page stop showing up.

Here is my set up:

**FOLDER**: website is inside a folder /site/

```
application/
favicon/
system/
index.php
.htaccess
robots.txt
```

**CONTROLLER:** I've tested changing to CI_Controller - even though I'm working on CI 1.7.2 - and __construct()... didn't work

```
class Home extends Controller
{

    // SET LAYOUT DEFAULT
    public $layout = 'default';

    // SET TITLE DEFAULT
    public $title = '';

    // SET CSS DEFAULT
    public $css = array('scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox');

    // SET JAVASCRIPT DEFAULT
    public $js = array('scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack');

    function Home () {

        parent :: Controller();

        // LOAD Libraries
        $this->load->library(array('createdate','minitextile','showimages'));

        // LOAD Models
        $this->load->model('site_model');
    }

    function index () {

        $data['website_info']   = $this->config->item('w_infos');
        // LOAD VIEWS
        $this->load->view ('include/home_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**CONFIG** - I've put only the essencial here...

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://domain.com/site/";

$config['index_page'] = "";

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; // Tested with AUTO, didn't work

$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd';
```

**HTACCESS** - the files are based inside the folder /site/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /site/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

**ROUTES:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

**My Log:** This is **after** the controllers name change

```
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 15:54:22 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 15:54:22 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 15:54:22 --> URI Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-11-21 15:54:22 --> 404 Page Not Found --> home
```

Before the name change (to caps) it was like this:

```
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-11-21 14:08:28 --> 404 Page Not Found --> home/index
```

I know that I'm new, and there are a lot of post on this issue out there... I only ask after making some (a lot) of testing my self - at least as far as my knowledge goes :D I've been using this CI version and set up for a while - and been meaning to upgrade to CI 3 - and I've tested/changed everything I could imagine and faced over many different hosts/servers and still I could not find a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because

```
function Home () {

    parent :: Controller();

    // LOAD Libraries
    $this->load->library(array('createdate','minitextile','showimages'));

    // LOAD Models
    $this->load->model('site_model');
}
```

Should be http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // LOAD Libraries
    $this->load->library(array('createdate','minitextile','showimages'));

    // LOAD Models
    $this->load->model('site_model');
}
```

Make sure your file names correct also when upgrading Home.php only the first letter upper case. as explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oops yep typo it is fixed now

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I tried some combinations of upper case and parent::__construct... or parent :: Controller()... turned out to be a PHP configuration problem at the short_open_tag was Off on server.

Comment: @user3004782 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming is good to read also

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Thanks for the help... but it was a problem on the PHP configuration... the `short_open_tag` wasn't activated on the served... and it took me a while to see it! :p So tip: **Check some php config too.**